# LOCK TABLES WRITE giving errors

Tags: 6, database

When I use it then it then the form page load shows endless errors like table system not locked, undefined index, table cache not locked etc.

How to use it in Drupal?

I'm using LOCK TABLES for a small piece of my code:

```
 if(!AnuDonationTable::lock_tables())
                {
                    form_set_error('',"Fatal problem with database access");
                    $form_state['redirect'] = false;
                    return;
                }

                $ret = AnuDonationTable::verify_count($sno, $itemarr[0]['hidden_total_updatedrows']);

                if( false == $ret )
                {
                    form_set_error('',"Fatal problem with database access");
                    $form_state['redirect'] = false;
                    AnuDonationTable::unlock_tables();
                    return;
                }
                else if( -1 == $ret) 
                {
                    form_set_error('',"Underlying data has changed after your page load. Please refresh this page.");
                    $form_state['redirect'] = false;
                    AnuDonationTable::unlock_tables();
                    return;
                }
                //else success

                $query = "INSERT INTO {anu_donations_housekeeping} (sno2,status,updated_by) VALUES  
                       (%d,'cancel',$user->uid)";

                if( false === db_query($query,$sno))
                {
                    drupal_set_message("Fatal Error:Unable to add data in the database",'error');
                    $form_state['redirect'] = false;
                    AnuDonationTable::unlock_tables();
                    return;
                }
                else{

                    AnuDonationTable::unlock_tables();
                }
```